# How to extract an exact value from a response in Json?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

After a Post action on a certain Link I get the following answer

```
{"data":{"loginWithEmail":{"__typename":"LoginResponse","me":{"__typename":"User","username":"davishelenekb","displayname":"davishelenekb","avatar":"https://image.sitecdn.com/avatar/default11.png","partnerStatus":"NONE","role":"None","myChatBadges":[],"private":{"__typename":"UserPrivateInfo","accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtasdasdasdaslzaGVsZW5la2IiLCJkaXNwbGF5bmFtZSI6ImRhdmlzaGVsZW5la2IiLCJhdmF0YXIiOiJodHRwczovL2ltYWdlLmRsaXZlY2RuLmNvbS9hdmF0YXIvZGVmYXVsdDExLnBuZyIsInBhcnRuZXJfc3RhdHVzX3N0cmluZyI6Ik5PTkUiLCJpZCI6IiIsImxpZCI6MCwidHlwZSI6ImVtYWlsIiwicm9sZSI6Ik5vbmUiLCJvYXV0aF9hcHBpZCI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTYwOTE4NDQwNyadasdasdaNTkyNDA3LCJpc3MiOiJETGl2ZSJ9.cQXJFUEo7r4bQa2FPHvKAvjisEF1VKldhFdxOcZ3YTk","email":"email","emailVerified":true,"bttAddress":{"__typename":"MyBTTAddress","senderAddress":null}},"subCashbacked":true},"accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRhdmlzaGVsZW5la2IiLCJkaXNwbGF5bmFtZSI6ImRhdmlzaGVsZW5la2IiLCJhdmF0YXIiOiJodHRwczovL2ltYWdlLmRsaXZlY2RuLmNvbS9hdmF0YXIvZGVmYasdasdyIsInBhcnRuZXJfc3RhdHVzX3N0cmluZyI6Ik5PTkUiLCJpasdasdlwZSI6ImVtYWlsIiwicm9sZSI6Ik5vbmUiLCJvYXV0aF9hcHBpZCI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTYwOTE4NDQasd221DA3LCJpc3MiOiJETGl2ZSJ9.cQXJFUEo7r4bQa2FPHvKAvjisEF1VKldhFdxOcZ3YTk","twofactorToken":null,"err":null}}}
```

I just want to extract the key that is in
`"accessToken":"KEY"`,

How can I do this?

My Code

````
import requests
import json
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

#Set Modules
ua = UserAgent()
url = 'site'

#Read TXT
accounts = 'accounts\\accounts.txt'
with open(accounts) as line:
   login = line.readline()
   line = login.split(",")
   cnt = 1
email = line[0]
password = line[1]

#login
head = {
   '.......': '.........',
}

data = {
  ..........
}

test = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head)
if test.status_code == 200:
   print('Loged!')
   print(test.text)
else:
   print('Error') ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the text of the response, parse it as JSON, and then access the "accessToken" property:

```py
test = requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers=head)
if test.status_code == 200:
    parsed = json.loads(test.text)
    key = parsed['data']['loginWithEmail']['accessToken']
    print(key)
```

**Side note:**

This snippet assumes that the format of the returned JSON is well known and no error occurs. In a real-world scenario, you may want to add a few validations to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you need like this:

```
response = test.json()
print(response["data"]["loginWithEmail"]["me"]["private"]["accessToken"])
```